# local($?) in END blocks - Why does it matter what value was assigned to it?

Tags: perl, subroutine

At work, we encountered an error when interacting with child processes in an object's destructor, and eventually traced it to the $? variable being overwritten during the wait calls.  This happens after the call to exit(), so $? additionally meant our program's return code to the operating system.

Specifically, the perldoc talked about this sort of error:

> Inside an END subroutine $? contains the value that is going to be given to exit(). You can modify $? in an END subroutine to change the exit status of your program.

We don't want that to happen, so we put a `local $?=$?;` inside of every END block.  But now the programs return success to the OS while actually failing in their given task.

I managed to break it down into two sample programs.  One that works as intended, and one that fails. This occurs on both v5.8.8 and v5.10.1 for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Program A: (returns 0 to the operating system)

```
END{ local $?=$?; }
exit(100);
```

Program B: (returns 100 to the operating system)

```
END{ local $?=$?>>8; }
exit(100);
```

Why does it matter what value was assigned to the `local $?` in the end block?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem right. 5.16.1 behaves that way too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug in perl. Apparently self assignment of `$?` in `local` is broken:

```
% perl -wle '$? = 123; print "before: $?"; local $? = $?; print "after: $?"'    
before: 123
after: 0
```

But this version works fine:

```
% perl -wle '$? = 123; print "before: $?"; local $? = $? + 0; print "after: $?"'
before: 123
after: 123
```

Pretty bizarre.

A bug report has been [filed](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=116891).

Comment: Added link to bug report someone (you?) filed.